# not working logback in spring boot test exception error

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-boot-test

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class Test {
    @Test
    void test() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: null
at com.example.crawling.kospi.api.act.KospiCTR.kospiTop10(KospiCTR.java:18)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPriod="10 seconds">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <statusListener class="com.example.crawling.common.logback.PrintOnlyWarningLogbackStatusListener"/>

    <springProfile name="local">
        <property resource="logback-local.properties"/>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="test">
        <property resource="logback-test.properties"/>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="dev">
        <property resource="logback-dev.properties"/>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="real">
        <property resource="logback-real.properties"/>
    </springProfile>

    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="${log.config.path}"/>
    <property name="LOG_APP_ERROR_FILE" value="${LOG_PATH}/${log.config.app.error.name}"/>
    <property name="LOG_APP_WARN_FILE" value="${LOG_PATH}/${log.config.app.warn.name}"/>
    <property name="LOG_SQL_ERROR_FILE" value="${LOG_PATH}/${log.config.sql.error.name}"/>
    <property name="LOG_SQL_TRACE_FILE" value="${LOG_PATH}/${log.config.sql.trace.name}"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="APP_ERROR_APPENDER"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_APP_ERROR_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="APP_WARN_APPENDER"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_APP_WARN_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SQL_ERROR_APPENDER"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_SQL_ERROR_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SQL_TRACE_APPENDER"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="com.example.crawling.common.config.filter.CustomLogbackFilter">
            <levels>TRACE|DEBUG|INFO|WARN</levels>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_SQL_TRACE_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SQL_TRACE_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SQL_ERROR_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SQL_TRACE_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SQL_ERROR_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SQL_TRACE_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SQL_ERROR_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker"
            level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="APP_ERROR_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="APP_WARN_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have a simple spring boot project
ID 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
In Main Spring Boot, exception errors are recorded well
in the logback file appender, but test code exception errors
are not recorded. I suspect it is due to the operation of
e.printstacktrace(), but is there a solution?